# Unable to Configure Ubuntu 19.10 iso boot install in FOG Configurations Menu Item Settings

Tags: boot

I have an apparently working FOG install, and have been able to configure boot installs off iso for CentOS isos 8.1, 8.0 and 7.7.  These work.  However, when I try to extrapolate the working Parameters in Menu Item Settings of FOG to something reasonable looking for Ubuntu 19.10, I always get a failure.  The closest I seem to get is a partial boot with a complaint about initramfs.  I am glad to get further details, but it may be most helpful to state my goals here first:

1. I prefer to actually know more about what is going on here with both Ubuntu 19.10, and whatever it is that FOG seems to be needing to properly boot the install / live iso.  If possible, I'd like to not just have a pat set of parameters that work, but that I do not understand.  Therefore, if your response could include recommending specific online reading for something you find I obviously don't understand reasonably, I really want that feedback.  Eventually, I also need to set up clearlinux and probably other distros, so understanding what is going on will be vital.
2. That being said, a pat response that works is always a good starting point to refer back to.  Ubuntu 19.10 is the most needed item we need to be constantly installing where I work, and as it is the most like 20.04, and 20.04 will be released in a week, that will probably get us an answer there too, which will help.

Oddments:
If I just do a simple set of parameters like this:

```
:Ubuntu1910Netinstall
set base http://10.54.27.222/html/ubuntu1910
kernel ${base}/casper/vmlinuz initrd=initrd repo=${base} inst.geoloc=0 ip=dhcp noapic nomodeset apci=off modeset=off
initrd ${base}/casper/initrd
boot
```

It ends without a working root filesystem.

Perhaps for now I should stop there, and see if I can let readers drive intelligent questions I have not thought of.  I have tried around 35 combinations, and have the ability to try a new thing about every 10 minutes, but pretty much feel like I don't know what I'm doing or why.

Also, older versions that allege to work, like for 15.04, seem to have used nfs.  I have not tried that, because I don't see that used with FOG 1.5.?  If I should jump in and do that, you are welcome to yell at me for not so far doing so.  Now I will take a break, and that may be my next step anyway.

Comment: I will here post an example of things I'm trying.  I honestly don't know if this is close to working for Ubuntu 19.10, or if it simply has enough hooks on it that it always catches the side of some hapless fish.  At any rate, it boots apparently almost successfully, only to end up without a full running state, and the last message:  "Unable to find medium containing live filesystem...Busybox..."

Comment: :Ubuntu1910Try9Netinstall
set base http://ipaddress/html/ubuntu1910
kernel ${base}/casper/vmlinuz initrd=initrd ip=dhcp apci=off modeset=off
initrd ${base}/casper/initrd
boot

Comment: I just tried a combination I guessed from this post area:  https://forums.fogproject.org/topic/10944/using-fog-to-pxe-boot-into-your-favorite-installer-images/7

Comment: kernel tftp://${fog-ip}/ubuntu/19.10/vmlinuz
initrd tftp://${fog-ip}/ubuntu/19.10/initrd
imgargs vmlinuz root=/dev/nfs boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=${fog-ip}:/images/os/ubuntu/19.10/ locale=en_US.UTF-8 keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us toram quiet splash
boot || goto MENU

Comment: But that yields kernel panic, unable to mount root fs.

Comment: I have now tried several variations with NFS mounts, and have a working mount configuration too, but this also fails.

Comment: I just got a screen shot of my kernel panic, but it looks like I cannot post it here.  Anybody wants to see it, I'd be glad to forward.  Includes reference to S2600WT2R, BIOS SE5C610.86B.01.01..2203 and above that message that says:  swapper/0 Not tainted 5.3.0-18-generic #19-Ubuntu.  On the bottom it gives a call trace line set, and then finally:  VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,255)

Comment: I also re-tested my NFS mount, and that works just fine.

Comment: So I did get a success, albeit with a partly broken, but useable install.  I use George's new combination from our spiceworks back and forth which he posted here:  https://forums.fogproject.org/topic/10944/using-fog-to-pxe-boot-into-your-favorite-installer-images?_=1588001958782&lang=en-US

Comment: Again, the install mostly works, but when it comes up, it has a broken F1 console, like it thinks it should have X but does not.  I have not found a fix for this yet, and have posted about the behavior.  The main thing for the user is you can simply go to the <alt><F4> or other available console to get in normally.  Unfortunately, it does make a splash screen that makes it look like an unusable install.